# how can I group array of values inside of an object to another array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an object with array of values

---

`{firstName: ['John', 'Mike']}, lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith']}`,

---

Now i have an empty object with array

---

`const newData = {}` 
`newData.ppl = []`

---

how can I have this result in `ppl` array like: `ppl = [{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}, {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick implementation with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const srcData = {
  firstName: ['John', 'Mike'],
  lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith']
};

const ppl = Object
  .entries(srcData)
  .reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
    values.forEach((val, i) => {
      if (i >= acc.length) {
        acc.push({});
      }
      acc[i][key] = val;
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(ppl);
```

Explanation:

1. Use `Object.entries` to get turn the object into an array of key-value pairs.
2. Use `.reduce` to iteratively build up the result array.
3. Use `.forEach` to loop over the array of values obtained from (1), pushing an empty object to the array (`push({})`) if the result array isn't long enough to hold all the items in the current array of values

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the `firstName` with `Array.forEach()`, and take the first name. Use the index to take the respective last name from the `lastName` array. Push a new object with the first and last names to the `ppl` array.

```js
const data = {firstName: ['John', 'Mike'], lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith']};

const newData = { ppl: [] };

data.firstName.forEach((firstName, i) => 
  newData.ppl.push({ 
    firstName, 
    lastName: data.lastName[i] 
  })
);

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the entries and assign the properties to the same index as the array's values.

This works for any arbitrary count of properties.

```js
var data = { firstName: ['John', 'Mike'], lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith'] },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => (a.forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || {})[k] = v), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

using a map.

```js
let master = {firstName: ['John', 'Mike'], lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith']}

const newData = {};
newData.ppl = master.firstName.map((f,i) => {
  return {firstName: f, lastName: master.lastName[i]};
});

console.log(newData.ppl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Array.reduce()`, `Object.values()` and `Object.entries()` like this:

```js
const data = { firstName: ['John', 'Mike'], lastName: ['Doe', 'Smith'] };

const ppl = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, arr]) => {
  arr.forEach((v, i) => (acc[i] = (acc[i] || {}))[key] = v);
  return acc;
}, {});

const newData = { ppl: Object.values(ppl) };

console.log(newData);
```